# unable to change date format for user view in cjuidatepicker in yii1

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii, jquery-ui-datepicker, yii1.x

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
                            'name'=>'date_from',
                            'id' => 'date_from',
                            //'value'=> date('d/m/Y',strtotime($date_from)),
                            'options'=>array(
                            'dateFormat' =>'dd/mm/yy',
                            'altFormat' =>'dd/mm/yy',
                            'changeMonth' => true,
                            'changeYear' => true,                                
                            'showAnim'=>'slide',
                            'showButtonPanel'=>true,
                        ),
                        'language' => 'en-GB',
                        'htmlOptions'=>array(
                            'class'=>'form-control'
                        ),
                    ));
```

This is the code for the date picker so I want the user to view the date in the following format: dd/mm/yy. I want it seperated with slashes.

Comment: What errors have you received? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: I didn't get any error but the date is not dispalying the way i want which is (dd-mm-yy). it's still still displaying the default which is (mm-dd-yy)

Comment: What do you want, dashes or slashes to separate the numbers? You say dashes, and then your example uses slashes. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Don't add comments.

Comment: I have edited the question... can you help with a fix now?

Answer (score 0):

This works in `Yii 1.20` with `JQuery 1.11.2` I added additional parameters just as reference.

```php
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
          'model'       => $model,
          'attribute'   => 'date_from',
          'language'    => 'en',
          'options'     => array(
              'showAnim'          => 'fold',
              'dateFormat'        => 'yy/mm/dd',
              'showOtherMonths'   => true,
              'selectOtherMonths' => true,
              'changeYear'        => true,
              'changeMonth'       => true,
              'yearRange'         => "2000:2020",
              'showWeek'          => false,
              'firstDay'          => 1
          ),
          'htmlOptions' => array(
              'size'      => '10',
              'maxlength' => '10',
              'class'     => 'form-control'
          )
      ));
```